# Cómo automatizar pruebas de software con appium para dispositivos iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, appium

Alguien pudiera ejemplificarme cómo automatizar pruebas de software con appium para dispositivos iOS?

He visto que la manera clásica es usando el XCode al que se conecta Appium pero en mi empresa están usando HeadSpin y se me dificulta mucho capturar los componentes de la app.

Cualquier idea o sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Las pruebas en Xcode tanto del código como de la UI funciona bien sin necesidad de otros componentes.